# App crashes when changes are made in Realm database

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When I update Realm database by adding one more table and installing app without uninstalling previous app. Application does not update Realm database. Some time it gets crashed.

Comment: update db version number then only your db will be updated with new table

Comment: No exceptions no code, no answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost 100% positive that this has to do with your RealmConfiguration. Are you setting `deleteRealmIfMigrationRequired` when you build the configuration? If not, are you setting the schema version and providing a migration?

If you're not doing one of these two things, you're... well, pretty much hosed, which kind of sounds like what you're seeing.

Comment: After adding "deleteRealmIfMigrationRequired" resolved the issue.

Comment: Using this method will clear exiting data right? Is there any way to retain the data and make changes to table?